# SQL get the last time number was set to 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a sql table similar to the below. I would like to get the last time it was changed from 0 to 1 and the last time it changed back to 0 (highlighted below for an example id).

[image]

What I have tried is:

```
select * from Table t1 join Table t2 on t1.id = t2.id join Table t3 on t1.id = t3.id 
where t1.flag = 1 and t2.flag = 0 and t3.flag 
group by t1.id
having min(t1.createdtime) between max(t2.createdtime) and min(t3.createdtime)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this dataset, you could use `lag()` to bring in the flag of the previous row, use it as a filter condition, and then aggregate:

```
select 
    id,
    max(createdtime) createdtime,
    flag
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(flag) over(partition by id order by createdtime) lagflag
    from mytable t
) t
where (flag = 0 and lagflag = 1) or (flag = 1 and lagflag = 0)
group by id, flag
```

Comment: I can't edit since it's one letter.... "oder by" should be "order by"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lag()` to get the recent flag. So you can filter for changes, i.e. when the (current) flag and the recent flag relate as desired. To get only the most recent of the changes you can filter by `row_number()`.

```
SELECT z.id,
       z.createdtime,
       z.flag
       FROM (SELECT y.id,
                    y.createdtime,
                    y.flag FROM (SELECT x.id,
                                        x.createdtime,
                                        x.flag,
                                        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.id
                                                           ORDER BY x.createdtime DESC) rn
                                        FROM (SELECT t.id,
                                                     t.createdtime,
                                                     t.flag,
                                                     lag(t.flag) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id
                                                                       ORDER BY createdtime) recentflag
                                                     FROM elbat t) x
                                                     WHERE x.flag = 0
                                                           AND x.recentflag = 1) y
                    WHERE y.rn = 1
             UNION ALL
             SELECT y.id,
                    y.createdtime,
                    y.flag FROM (SELECT x.id,
                                        x.createdtime,
                                        x.flag,
                                        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY x.id
                                                           ORDER BY x.createdtime DESC) rn
                                        FROM (SELECT t.id,
                                                     t.createdtime,
                                                     t.flag,
                                                     lag(t.flag) OVER (PARTITION BY t.id
                                                                       ORDER BY createdtime) recentflag
                                                     FROM elbat t) x
                                                     WHERE x.flag = 1
                                                           AND x.recentflag = 0) y
                    WHERE y.rn = 1) z
       ORDER BY z.createdtime DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `lag()` in a `CTE` to get the previous flag for each row and then `NOT EXISTS`:

```
with cte as(
    select *, lag(flag) over(partition by id order by createdtime) prevflag
    from tablename 
) 
select c.id, c.createdtime, c.flag
from cte c
where c.flag <> c.prevflag 
and not exists (
  select 1 from cte
  where id = c.id and flag = c.flag and prevflag = c.prevflag and createdtime > c.createdtime
)
order by c.createdtime
```

Or:

```
with cte as(
    select *, lag(flag) over(partition by id order by createdtime) prevflag
    from tablename 
)
select id, max(createdtime) createdtime, flag
from cte
where flag <> prevflag 
group by id, flag
order by createdtime
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=536b5dbd9b548c865359c94c8cdb45fb).
Results:

```
> id | createdtime         | flag
> -: | :------------------ | ---:
>  5 | 2019-11-02 14:30:00 |    1
>  5 | 2020-08-01 14:30:00 |    0
```